# facebook says that The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have created a web application (https://www.atalki.com/) and testing the application with facebook debugger tools just to make sure the urls are appearing properly and perfect in whatsapp and other social media channels.
But for some reason, all my og tags are ignored.

The only of meta tag which I have not mentioned is

The other tags are mentioned.

[image]

```
<meta property="og:title" content="atalki" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="og:description" content="Documents to shareable websites, within seconds" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.atalki.com/" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.atalki.com/static/media/Logo_For_Whatsapp.c3b71cbc.jpg" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="atalki" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="og:type" content="website" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg/png/svg/jpg" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="312" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="312" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="atalki" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@doc2qa" data-react-helmet="true">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@doc2qa" data-react-helmet="true">
```

Not sure where I am going wrong here.
Also, when echoed the whole code, I am not able to see any of the meta tags.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.atalki.com%2F

I am pretty sure, I am doing something silly but not sure what it is . Can any one please help me here.

Comment: Your server is not returning any og-tags. My guess is that you are using some Javascript framework and that is what adds the og-tags. That will not work. Your server needs to include the tags in the HTML that is sent to Facebook when they request the URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot @WizKid. I can  see all the  tags rendered in chrome console. This means the sever is sending the og-tags right?

Comment: I am using React as the javascript framework

Comment: No it doesn't. React runs in the web browser. If you aren't doing server rendering. Which if you don't know you aren't.

Comment: @WizKid - Thanks . Got it. I am not doing server rendering. I will change it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue. The OpenGraph tags are showing up in the Facebook debugger, but still that message.

Url: https://www.inspiration-for-success.com/highest-price-bitcoin-btc-ever/ or any other url on that site as far as I know.

Improved some things like adding width and heigth for the image, but doesn't make any difference.